# Can SOSL retrieve child objects from the result set of parent objects?

Tags: sosl

I have contact object and Registration Custom Object.

I want to list the registration object fields in contact object using relationship as follows:

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT id,name FROM Registrations__r) FROM Contact;
```

I want to do the same thing using SOSL. is that Possible?
I did something like this for Contact fields.

```
FIND 'searchText' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(name,Email);
```

doesnot know how to use registration object fields here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is covered by the inestimable wisdom of @sfdcfox here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008yxvIAA

I quote:

> The documentation does not provide an example for this type of query, so I presume that one does not exist (it is not supported). Also, you can't apparently use SOSL as a subquery to SOQL; I couldn't find an example for this syntax either. This leads me to believe that the correct method for doing something like this would be a two-parter that looks like this:

```
List<account> accountSearch = 
    ((List<Account>)[find 'test' in all fields returning account(id)][0]);

list<account> accounts = 
    [select id,name,(select id,firstname,lastname from contacts) 
        from account where id in :accountSearch];
```

> end quote

In your case, you'll do something like this:

```
List<Contact> contactSearch = 
    ((List<Contact>)[find 'searchtext' in all fields returning Contact(id)][0]);

list<Contact> contacts = 
    [select id,email,name,(select id,name from registrations__r) 
        from contact where id in :contactSearch];
```