# Search in related objects fields

Tags: relationships, sosl

Is there a way to make a single SOSL query to search in fields of related objects?

For example: "find all tasks related to accounts are named X*".

Comment: Please refer this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48187/can-sosl-retrieve-child-objects-from-the-result-set-of-parent-objects

Comment: And https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm